# New added page doesn't work in ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have application in ZEND Framework 1.
I want to add new page, and go to this page instead of old one.

But the problem is, redirection to new page doesn't work, and I dont know why.

Some snippets:
In IndexController in function init:

```
        ...
        // THIS IS OLD PAGE
        case $this->view->root_by_names['register']['root_furl']:
                $this->view->root_name = 'register';
                $this->_forward( 'register' );
                break;

        // THIS IS NEW PAGE
        case $this->view->root_by_names['register2']['root_furl']:
            $this->view->root_name = 'register2';
            $this->_forward( 'register2' );
            break;
       ...

// old action (working ok)
public function registerAction(){
     $this->_redirect( $this->view->CreateUrl( array( $this->view->root_by_names['register']['root_furl'] ) ) );
}

// new action (doesn't work)
public function register2Action(){
         $this->_redirect( $this->view->CreateUrl( array( $this->view->root_by_names['register2']['root_furl'] ) ) );
    }
```

DB entry for redirection functionality:
[image]

Form submitted in view:

```
// WORKING
<form method="get" action="<?=$this->CreateUrl( array( $this->root_by_names['register']['root_furl'], 'producer' ) )?>">
    <button id="button-new-account-producer" class="submit">NEXT</button>

</form>


// DOESN'T WORK
<form method="get" action="<?=$this->CreateUrl( array( $this->root_by_names['register2']['root_furl'], 'producer' ) )?>">
    <button id="button-new-account-producer" class="submit">NEXT</button>
</form>
```

Rejestracja - old page
Rejestracja2 - new page

For old page (working) I am redirected to new page.
For new page - I stay in current page somehow.

register2 page is a copy of register on FTP.

I hope I provided all informations. Is shouldn't be complicated. 
Can anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong for new page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The was a other layer, where the request are filtered. It is not ZF issue, but previous dev issue.